# eigenvalue of a 'norm' matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$ distinct real numbers, and matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is defined as
$$
a_{ij}=|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|.
$$
I guess $A$ has a positive eigenvalue and $n-1$ negative eigenvalue by calculating for cases $n=2,3$. For general $n$ I verify it by **MATLAB** but have no idea about how to prove.

Any idea or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have proven it with help of my friend. W.L.O.G. suppose
$$
\lambda_1<\lambda_2<\cdots<\lambda_n.
$$
and denote
$$
t_k = \lambda_k-\lambda_{k-1}.
$$
Then for any $x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&\cdots&x_n\end{pmatrix}^T$, weite $s_k=\sum_{i=1}^kx_i$, we have
$$
\sum_{i\neq j}|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|x_ix_j=2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)x_ix_j=2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^jt_kx_ix_j\\
=2\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=k}^nt_kx_ix_j=2\sum_{k=2}^nt_k\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}x_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=k}^nx_j\right)=2\sum_{k=2}^nt_ks_{k-1}(s_n-s_{k-1})\\
=2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t_{k+1}s_{k}(s_n-s_{k})=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t_{k+1}\left(s_n^2-(s_n-2s_k)^2\right).
$$
And we are done.